# Do not load images in jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, google-chrome-extension, block

Well I'm making a chrome extension that parses some webpage, and that's working right, but I would like to be able to block images, meaning, not to load them, since all the parsing is made in background and it would be faster without the images... is there a way to do so?

```
$("#data").load(url, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){ 
    $('img').attr('src','');
    if(XMLHttpRequest.status==200)
        parseLinks();
    else if(XMLHttpRequest.status==301)
        Text="Please login.";
    else
        Text = "Error.";
    console.log(textStatus);
});

function parseLinks(){
  Text = [];
  $("#data .plain").each(function(i){
    var tempArray;// = [];
    var parent = "#"+$(this).parent().attr("id");
    tempArray['text']   = $(parent+' a').text();
    tempArray['link']   = $(parent+' a').attr('href');
    tempArray['ad']     = $(parent+' font[color="#808080"]').text();
    tempArray['value']  = $(parent+' td[width="100"] font').text();
    Text[i] = tempArray;
      });
  if(Text.lenght)
    console.log("ads loaded!");
  else
    Text = "No new ads.";
  console.log(Text);
 }
```

Also, the more time you keep running the extension the more ram an vram the extension will be using, since it accumulates the images in each of the ajax request...

Comment: Ajax requests just get a string of HTML. Do you mean you want to remove images from that HTML before putting it in the page? If so, we need code to see what you're doing to insert it.

Comment: I want to not load images in the ajax request, like when in your browser you disable images and so on, I guess it's not possible...
I've tried this
 $('img').attr('src','');
in the callback but I guess it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, I had to change from `.load()` to `$.get()` to be able to remove images via `.replace()` before the html requested is inserted in the page, here's the code:

```
$.get(url, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){ 
    console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
    if(XMLHttpRequest.status==200) {
        var loggedin = responseText.search('<div class=header>Account Login</div>');
        if(loggedin == -1){
            responseText = responseText.replace(/<img/gi, '<noload');
            parseLinks(responseText);
        } else {
            Text="Please login.";
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:'L'});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[180,180,180,255]});
        }
    } else {
        Text = "Error.";
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:'\u00D7'});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[255,0,0,255]});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, are you sure about that? When i try similar code, it still loads all the images in the DOM but filters it before rendering.